# How to live-stream 360 video from a PC to VR headset/goggle/HMD?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, gstreamer, oculus, 360-degrees

I have some code that captures footage from cameras and outputs a stitched 360 video. I can output stitched videos as `MP4` files, `RGBA` files, or `RGBA OpenGL` textures.

I need to somehow get my code to live-stream the stitched video to a VR headset (preferably a tethered VR headset like Oculus Rift CV1 as opposed to a headset containing a cellphone).

I need to stream the stitched 360 video from the PC to the headset without an internet connection, and I would prefer having a wired connection.

Given these conditions, what are my options? Can I use something like `ffmpeg` or `Gstreamer` to send the video stream over USB (or another wired connection) to the VR headset?

I have looked into the documentation for both `ffmpeg` and `Gstreamer`, while it seems plausible, I don't know a clear way to do it yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Unity and SteamVR to live stream to HTC Vive and potentially Oculus. This tutorial "[Tutorial: Live Ricoh Theta S Dual Fish Eye for SteamVR in Unity](http://lists.theta360.guide/t/tutorial-live-ricoh-theta-s-dual-fish-eye-for-steamvr-in-unity/938?u=jcasman)" may help. It covers live streaming over USB and suggests that HDMI output should be possible, too.